# How to get a verified SSL certificate for local development?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ssl

I have a Ruby on Rails app that uses SSL. I run the server using `thin start --ssl`. Every time I launch the server and access the app, I get a warning saying that the SSL certificate is not verified. That is not a problem as long as I stay in Rails. However, my app also has an API and I am developing an iPhone client app for it. When I do a request from the iphone app to the local Rails server, I get the following error:

> 2013-03-24 12:30:09.680 OAuth2Test[44541:c07] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “oauth.lvh.me” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x8832730 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://oauth.lvh.me:3000/oauth/authorize?client_id=23b8921e8db833a33ac7a058b93183a1496f56a6eea4f6c597291106f80a37d0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcatapultcentral.com%2FiOSClientCallback&response_type=code, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://oauth.lvh.me:3000/oauth/authorize?client_id=23b8921e8db833a33ac7a058b93183a1496f56a6eea4f6c597291106f80a37d0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcatapultcentral.com%2FiOSClientCallback&response_type=code, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “oauth.lvh.me” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0x8944cd0 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “oauth.lvh.me” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=}

In my opinion, the key part of this error is: `"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “oauth.lvh.me” which could put your confidential information at risk."`. By the way, I test my iPhone app in the iPhone Simulator.

So, if I am correct, there are three solutions to this problem:

1. Deploy my API to the staging server and develop the iPhone app against that. At the moment, all the API-related code is not deployed, and I'd rather not deploy it until it is in a stable state. So that is not an option.
2. Develop the iPhone app in a certain way so that it doesn't verifies the SSL certificate. I do not like this approach and I don't even know how to do it...
3. Get a local **verified** SSL certificate (fake the verified state or something). I don't know how to do that but that seems like the best option.

I tried to follow [a tutorial](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) on how to generate a self certified SSL certificate and then run the Rails server with `thin start --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file server.key --ssl-cert-file server.crt` but that didn't work (the created SSL certificate is still not verified).

So how can I solve my problem please?

Comment: You should create a root CA and use it to create your SSL certificates, and add that root CA to your iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First, I test my app on the iPhone Simulator, which makes it more complicated. Second, I have no clue how to do what you suggested...

Comment: @grasGendarme I did some research following your advice and problem solved! I am using [this python script](https://github.com/ADVTOOLS/ADVTrustStore). Please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped :) I'm posting it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a root CA and use it to create your SSL certificates, and add that root CA to your iPhone.